# Multiple FBX Animation Files in Maya

Tags: animation, rendering, spritesheet, maya, fbx

I bought some animated models which came as FBX files from the unity asset store and I'm trying to export them to PNG sprite sheets in Maya (for an html5 web project).

The file seems to be main fbx (character.fbx) and then an FBX file for each animation named character@animation.fbx.

I was wondering if there was a way for me to import all of these fbx files into Maya and then batch render each animation to PNG frames with some naming/directory structure?

Currently, I can import the main character fbx and an animation fbx and then render that single animation. This works, but it's tedious. Is there anyway to render all the animations at once?

Answer (score 1):

In Maya, if you can do it by hand, then you can script it. The easiest way to do is to do it once, then open the script editor and look at the output. You will see the sequence of MEL commands Maya executed. Based on that, it is normally easy to write a MEL script that does the same but for a bunch of files located in a directory.